# Is this AJAX deprecated? How can I update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been searching for a solution to Ajax my WordPress site, so that a post when clicked, will show up without reloading the webpage. Pretty standard these days I think.

It's a fullscreen style website that shows 1 post at a time and I would like to be able to have a simple navigation and next/prev functionality that when clicked will display the next post without reloading.

I'm starting to get the gist that the script may be deprecated and no longer accepted in the current version of WordPress and jQuery.

I'm not looking to have any spinning icons or that jazz, just a simple change in opacity. Currently my script is as follows. (#container being my main wrap and #content being the actual content within the container that I would like replaced.)

```
(function() {
    
var $container = $("#container"),
    siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
    $internalLinks = $("a[href^='"+ siteURL +"']"),
    hash = window.location.hash,
    URL = '',
    $el;
    
    
if (hash) {
    
    $container.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
    hash = hash.substring(1);
    URL = hash + " #content";
    $container.load(URL, function() {
        $container.animate({opacity: "1"});
    });
            
    
}       

$internalLinks.each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
}).click(function() {
    $container.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
    $el = $(this);
    URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
    URL = URL + " #content";
    $container.load(URL, function() {
        $container.animate({opacity: "1"});
    });
            
    
}); 

});
```

Comment: At the top where it says `(function() {`, replace that with `jQuery(function($) {` and it will probably work a lot better.

Comment: answer to topic is none of methods used in code are deprecated. Very hard to help without being able to see what's happening in a browser console within your code, or knowing what output is of the various url's being used